# Methods of hacking aspx website

Tags: asp.net, .net, cookies

**Intro:**
I have a website developed by some consultant. Website is behind a login and the users have to fill out forms in 8 pages and then submit in the final page.

**Problem:**
He is using viewstate to load and save the data. He has left it only encoded (not encrypted). Anyone can decode the viewstate by using the base64 decoding.

**Question 1:**
Are there any potential ways to hack the information based on this loophole (viewstate not encrypted)

**One more issue:** I am not sure how is he generating the cookies, but if I replace the cookies of one user with other(using cookie manager for firefox), the login is getting changed.

**Question 2:** Is there a possibility that some hacker can generate cookies and hack the login. Does .net generate random cookies or the developer has to generate cookies based on the user info.

Comment: Look at the OWASP Top 10 https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project#tab=OWASP_Top_10_for_2013. Be sure that you're safe with injection (A1) or cross site scripting (A3) when you process the data filled in the form. It isn't because your users have to be identified that they can't break your system. Especially if hackers have been successful in stealing login/passwords to your users (with phishing attacks for instance)

Comment: Thanks @PierrOz 
I tested SQL injection and XSS. My website is not vulnerable to those. Only thing bothering is viewstate encoding and cookie hijacking.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to both questions,

1. Encrypting viewstate is not that difficult, you can simply turn it on in config file for entire website. Unless any sensitive information is stored in viewstate, encryption will just slow down your server as number of users will grow. **Correct approach is not to encrypt, but not to store any sensitive information** in viewstate at all. Instead use session or server side cache to store sensitive information that way no one will have access. Ideally you should get code reviewed to see if any sensitive information is stored in Viewstate or not.
2. You cannot do anything for changing cookie problem, because it is responsibility of user to logout when leaving desk unattended. If you login to your site, leave desk open for someone else to mess with, server has no way to identify whether it is you who initially logged in or someone else, unless you periodically check user behavior etc. Many companies check IP address and various other factors to see if cookie hijacking is being done, but on the same machine, same browser, if you swap cookies of two users, unless some advanced behavior logging is done to identify user, there is no way server can differentiate it.

Default Forms Authentication of ASP.NET is very strong, and very well encrypted. Unless hacker has access to `machineKey` (configurable in web.config, and uniquely generated for every machine), hacker cannot generate cookies. You can certainly make algorithm stronger by changing config. But defaults are pretty strong anyway.